# How to reference a JavaScript function into a HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

For some reason in PyCharm I've had trouble including JavaScript code into a HTML file, therefore I decided to create a separate JS file so I can place the code in there instead.

The problem I have now, is trying to reference the function in the body within the HTML file. How can I do this?

JavaScript code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit-button").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/chatbot",
          data: {
              question: $("#question").val()
          },
          success: function(result) {
            $("#response").append("<br>Me: "+$("#question").val()+ "<br> Morty: "+result.response);
            $("#question").val("")
          },
          error: function(result) {
              alert('error');
          }
      });

    });

  });
}
```

I've tried to paste the HTML code but its giving me a formatting error, therefore I've pasted an image below:

Where I've put `<script src="convo.js></script>` where I would like to reference the JS function.

[image: HTML code]

Comment: Please don't include images of code, you can use the code formatting options in the editor to avoid formatting errors.

Comment: Have you tried using `./convo.js`?

Comment: Do not post code as image. Visit https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question to find out the reason.

Comment: So, is the JS code in your question the `convo.js` we see in the HTML?

Comment: i've just attempted to use ./convo instead but that isnt working. @DBS yes the JS code in my question is the convo.js in the HTML

Comment: Are the 2 files in the same folder

Comment: Yes both the convo.js file and the HTML file are in the same folder called "templates"

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your folder of this project, if your scripts are in the same folder as the HTML file then just calling out the script filename is `src` is enough otherwise `src` will need the relative path of the script.

What is your folder structure?